# how to dynamically show number of filled Fields in infopath

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

I Have a info-path with lots of fields and I want user to know the status of fields  completed under each tab(View).
How dynamically I can show the number of blank fields still remains as a continuous  Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For each text field, create a corresponding integer field and give it a default value of 1.
2. Create rules on the text field that update the integer field depending on whether the text field is blank or not blank -- when the text field is not blank, set the integer field to 0. When the text field is blank, set the integer field to 1.
3. Create a calculated value that sums the values of the integer fields. This will tell you how many fields are remaining to be completed.

To make the answer readable I have assumed text fields but the same principle could be applied to other fields.

You can see a simple example here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9278601/fields-remaining.xsn

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Although i have solved this with the help of count method, but your answer is also correct.one more question if you know when publishing this to share point I am getting the post back issue that while filling fields of the for.. do you know things related to this ..Thanks in advance

Comment: You're welcome. Postbacks can have different causes depending on the structure of your form. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2008/06/19/designing-browser-enabled-forms-for-performance-in-infopath-forms-services-part-2.aspx) from the Microsoft InfoPath team lists ten possible causes.

Comment: Ironically your solution is a filtered down option to stop Postback issue ..  wish I could have a chance to double tick the answer :)..